# How to use lsusb in a Docker container to get USB device descriptions?

Tags: debian, usb, docker

In a Docker container:

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged debian bash
root@fe612fde137f:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y usbutils && lsusb
... snip ...
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002  
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 1a86:5512  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001  
root@fe612fde137f:/#
```

On the host:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 1a86:5512 QinHeng Electronics CH341 in EPP/MEM/I2C mode, EPP/I2C adapter
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
$
```

Any idea how to get USB device descriptions from inside the Docker container?

---

**Solution**: `usb.ids` is present, but not `hwdb.bin` (hardware database).

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged debian bash
root@fe612fde137f:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y usbutils && find / -type f \( -name "usb.ids" -o -name "hwdb.bin" \)
/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids
root@fe612fde137f:/#
```

This means `udev` is not installed. To fix, `apt install udev` on debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `/usr/share/usb.ids` (and/or `[/usr]/lib/udev/hwdb.bin` if your distribution has it) be present within the container.

If your container works well otherwise, it seems you only need those files for `lsusb`. While adding the `udev` package to be included into the container build process is possible, it might be overkill in this case.

The `hwdb.bin` file is created dynamically by the `systemd-hwdb update` command, sourcing the information from `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/*.hwdb` and `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/*.hwdb` files. To keep the container as lightweight as possible, you might want to create the `hwdb.bin` outside the container (or use the file from your container builder host) and just inject the end product `hwdb.bin` into the actual container.

I ran `lsusb` under `strace` to find out all the locations it tries to find the `hwdb.bin` file from:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/udev/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/udev/hwdb.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Within a container, you could put the `hwdb.bin` file into whichever of those locations makes the most sense to you.

Comment: If you can expand your answer, then I can accept it. I had to do my own research to find out how to get `hwdb.bin` into the distro.